# How to get Mono's WebBrowser control running under Linux

Tags: linux, mono, webbrowser-control

I have set up Linux Mint 15 on a VM and installed MonoDevelop afterwards. Now I'm trying to use the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control but I get a NullReferenceException when I try to navigate to a page. The underlying IWebBrowser's Navigation property seems to be the culprit. But why it's null I have no idea. The same happens when I use it with GTK#.

There seems to be an old unresolved bug report about this. But I also found a comment from a Mono developer on a mailing list saying that it works for him. There seem to be no tutorials or blog entries about this and my Linux/Mono knowledge is quite limited.

So what is needed to get this working? Or are there any alternatives to embed a browser into a Mono GUI?

Comment: This worked for me when I used it a year or two ago. Where's that bug report? Do you have Firefox installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have Firefox installed. The bug report can be found [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=581627).